# NoSuchMethodError in Vertx when hitting an API

Tags: java, api, vert.x

I am using Vertx to manage APIs. When I hit the API, I get a NoSuchMethodError. The error is given below:

> io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext - Unhandled exception in router
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextDecorator.(io.vertx.ext.web.Route,
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextInternal)'

Can anyone help on what could be causing this error?

Comment: if you are using docker image of vertx then mention vcomplete on image name vertx/vertx4:<version>
eg: vertx/vertx4:4.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely case for this error is that your project is including vert.x dependencies with different versions. For example, vert.x core is 4.3.1 and vert.x web is 4.2.7.

I'd recommend you to use your build tool or IDE to verify the versions of the dependencies your project is using and make sure that they all align to the same `semver`.

Comment: Yes. This was the issue. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

- What can cause `NoSuchMethodError` with provided exception message ?

As [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) suggests, it thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.
Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed, specifically in your provided message it located on `RoutingContextDecorator` void method, see more in [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/impl/RoutingContextDecorator.java).